# Pydantic - parse a list of objects from YAML configuration file

Tags: python, yaml, pydantic

I want to read a list of objects from a YAML file:

```yaml
- entry1:
   attribute: "Test1"
   amount: 1
   price: 123.45
- entry2:
   attribute: "Test1"
   amount: 10
   price: 56.78
```

For this data structure i created three nested models as follows:

```py
# Models
class EntryValues(BaseModel):
    attribute: str
    amount: int
    price: float

class Entry(BaseModel):
    entry1: EntryValues
    entry2: EntryValues
class Config(BaseModel):
    __root__: list[Entry]
```

My code to read the YAML config file looks as follows:

```py
# get YAML config path
def get_cfg_path() -> Path:
    return CWD

# read YAML file
def read_cfg(file_name: str, file_path: Path = None) -> YAML:
    if not file_path:
        file_path = get_cfg_path()

    if file_path:
        try:
            file = open(file_path / file_name, "r")
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"open file {file_name} failed", e)
            sys.exit(1)
        else:
            return load(file.read())
    else:
        raise Exception(f"Config file {file_name} not found!")
```

Now i want to unpack the values of the YAML to my model. For that i tried to unpack the values with the `**` operator. I think im missing one more loop here though, but i can not get it work.

```py
# Unpack and create config file
def create_cfg(file_name: str = None) -> Config:
    config_file = read_cfg(file_name=file_name)
    _config = Config(**config_file.data)
    return _config
```

I would appreciate any help.

## Update

So i played around with my model-structure a bit without using the YAML file. I dont quite get why the following throws an `ValidationError`:

Consider the following list of entries (thats the same data structure i would receive from my YAML file):

```py
entries = [
    {'entry1': {'attribute': 'Test1', 'amount': 1, 'price': 123.45}}, 
    {'entry2': {'attribute': 'Test2', 'amount': 10, 'price': 56.78}}
]
```

If i run the following simple loop, then Pydantic throws an `ValidationError`:

```py
for entry in entries:
    Entry(**entry)
```

Error:

```bash
ValidationError: 1 validation error for Entry
entry2
  field required (type=value_error.missing)
```

However, if the list only contains one entry dictionary, then it works:

```py
class Entry(BaseModel):
    entry1: EntryValues
    #entry2: EntryValues

entries = [
    {'entry1': {'attribute': 'Test1', 'amount': 1, 'price': 123.45}}
]

for entry in entries:
    Entry(**entry)
```

Can someone explain this or what im doing wrong here?

Comment: Can you convert yaml input to json? That might be the easier path.

Comment: Why would converting to JSON be any easier? They are both just serialization formats that will need essentially identical code to transform them into Python data structures.

Comment: When you say, "I can not get it to work", what exactly is happening? Are you getting an error? Unexpected behavior? Something else?

Comment: @larsks i can not unpack with the `**` operator because it requires a mapping, not a list. I tried to use the `parse_obj` function form Pydantic like this: `_config = Config.parse_obj(config_file.data)` but that causes a ValidationError. Maybe my modeling is wrong or it requires a different data structure in my yaml file to get it to work. My Pydantic knowledge is limited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your update, the reason that the second case works but not the first is that the unpacking operator (`**`) takes a single dictionary object which contains all the necessary keys. In your first case, you had one dictionary with all the necessary info; in the second it is spread across two dicts and they can't be unpacked together. One possible workaround would be to merge them into a single dictionary. But as far as I understand, a better solution would be to just change your YAML to provide this in the first place, by deleting the first two characters in each line:

```
entry1:
 attribute: "Test1"
 amount: 1
 price: 123.45
entry2:
 attribute: "Test1"
 amount: 10
 price: 56.78
```

and then:

```
_config = Config(__root__=[Entry(**entries)])
```

### Original answer:

There are a number of issues with your code, but I think what you're trying to do is parse the YAML into a dictionary and instantiate an `EntryValues` from each item. That would look something like this:

```
from pydantic import BaseModel
from pathlib import Path
from typing import List

import yaml


def create_cfg(file_name: str = None) -> Config:
    config_file = read_cfg(file_name=file_name)
    entries = yaml.safe_load(config_file)
    _config = [
        EntryValues(**di[name]) for di, name in zip(entries, ["entry1", "entry2"])
    ]
    return _config
```

Comment: Thats pretty much what i wanted, thank you! However, it would be cool if `_config` has objects of type `Entry` not `EntryValues`. So that i can iterate a list of `Entry`'s. Thats what i wanted to achieve in the `Config` model.

Comment: Ah, I see. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks again! Your version of the YAML file and mine are the same though. Both versions will return a list of entries and therefore unpacking with `Config(__root__=[Entry(**entries)])` will cause the following error `TypeError: __main__.Entry() argument after ** must be a mapping, not list`. For now, ill stick with your original solution though.

Comment: You're welcome. They're not the same though: you have dashes before `entry1` and `entry2`, which create a list, I don't. https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/YAMLSyntax.html